# Как мне в данном отрывке кода поставить параметры только для background - image

Tags: html, css

```
.the_main_inf{
  background-color: #f26522;
  height: 858px;
  background-image: url(Dom_Derevo.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Не понятен вопрос. Какие параметры? Как собираетесь их править?

Comment: Я хочу задать background-image значение padding-top: 720px

Comment: Думаю, что стоит использовать дополнительные элементы для этого, но также вы можете поэкспериментировать с background-position

Comment: Сергей, свойства CSS (background, padding и прочие) применяются к какому либо тегу html (например div или p) Соответственно назначить какое либо свойство CSS другому свойству CSS невозможно.